# Use file_get_contents to to download multiple files at same time in php?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

UDDATE: THIS IS AN S3 BUCKET QUESTION (SEE ANSWER)

I am looking to upload some code that reads files from an S3 bucket which uses the file_get_contents command to download a file one at a time.

Start

```
file_get_contents(s3://file1.json)
```

Wait until finished , then start next download:

```
file_get_contents(s3://file2.json)
```

And I want instead for them to all start at once to save time. like this:

Start both at same time:

```
file_get_contents(s3://file1.json)
file_get_contents(s3://file2.json)
```

Wait for them both at same time to finish.

I have seen multi curl requests but nothing for file_get_contents on this topic, is it possible ?

EDIT: Currently  the code I am looking at uses s3:// which doesn't seem to work with curl. This is a way of getting to Amazon's S3 bucket.

EDIT2: Sample of current code :

```
    function get_json_file( $filename = false ){

        if(!$filename) return false;

        // builds s3://somefile.on.amazon.com/file.json
        $path = $this->get_json_filename( $filename ); 

        if(!$filename || !file_exists($path)){
            return false;
        }
        elseif(file_exists($path))  {
            $data = file_get_contents($path);
        }
        else $data = false;
        return ( empty( $data ) ? false : json_decode( $data , true ));

    }
```

Comment: Now I'm sure you know the question on everyones mind, what is `s3`? A constant? because well, `:` is an invalid naming of a variable or constant.

Comment: And if you want 1 script to use `multiple` threads, either use curl or some sort of async include. `file_get_contents()` is simply a GET request from a resource.

Comment: s3:// works as it is for some reason, this is Amazon's private way of getting to data.  I can't use s3:// to access this using curl it appears.

Comment: Why not do `php -f downloader.php file1.json; php -f downloader.php file2.json`?

Comment: That is an idea but actually it just needs to be read into a variable.

Answer (score -1):

ANSWER: S3 SECURED, REQUIRES SPECIAL URI

Thank you guys for responding in comments. I was WAY off base with this earlier today when I asked this question.

This is the deal, the version of php we are using does not allow for threading. Hence, to ask for multiple URLs you need to use the multi curl option.  The s:// somehow worked with a class file for S3 that I missed before. Hence the weird naming.

ALSO, IMPORTANT, if you don't care about protecting the data on S3, you can just make it public and NOT have this issue. In my case the data needs to be somewhat protected so that requires a bunch of things in the URI.

You can use Amazon's S3 class to generate a secure link from the URI and the bucket name on S3. This will return the proper URL to use with your bucket. The S3 class can be downloaded manually or installed via composer in laravel for example. It requires that you install an user with a key to access this in the AWS console.

```
$bucketName = "my-amazon-bucket";
$uri = "/somefile.txt"
$secure_url = $s3->getObjectUrl($bucketName, $uri, '+5 minutes');
```

This will generate a valid URL to access the file on S3 which can be used with curl etc..

```
https://domain.s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/filename.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=myaccesskey&Expires=1305311393&Signature=mysignature
```